# Java Spring Webservices SOAP Authentication

Tags: java, spring, authentication, soap, wsdl

I am using java spring webservice to send soap requests to a server. However I get an error from the server saying

```
The security context token is expired or is not valid
```

So then I added authentication to the SOAP headers, resulting in request xml something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <env:Header>
      <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <UsernameToken>
            <Username>XXXXXXXX</Username>
            <Password>XXXXXXXX</Password>
         </UsernameToken>
      </Security>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      The body is in the correct format here
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

But I still get that error. From what I understand, the client sends authentication credentials to the server, the server sends back requestToken which is used to keep connection alive between client and server and then client using the token received from the server can make any other API calls such as login, buy, sell (or whatever mentioned in API)

Am I right in this assumption? If yes, how can this be implemented using Java Spring WebServices. Do I need to generate fields on client side like BinarySecret and package that under RequestSecurityContext?

For adding the SOAP headers, I wrote a class which implements WebServiceMessageCallback and overrides doWithMessage method and writes headers in that for username and password (i.e security)

Any help would be appreciated! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 2 days of finding out, I was able to figure out the solution!

1) Generate the classes from wsdl using CXF wsdl2java

2) Make sure in the pom file, you point to the correct wsdlLocation

3) Get the stub from the service class generated and inject username and password provided and then it should work. Something like this:

```
final YourService service = new YourService();
final YourStub stub = service.getService();

final Map ctx = ((BindingProvider)stub).getRequestContext();

ctx.put("ws-security.username", userName);
ctx.put("ws-security.password", password);

stub.callYourMethod();
```

PS: Please make sure you have the right libraries, I just used cxf-bundle and nothing else from cxf and it worked! Earlier it was not working as I had individually included libraries from cxf.